# Non-Symmetric Real Matrix Positive Real Eigenvalues and Complex Eigenvalues

Tags: matrices

There is a way to determine the number of real eigenvalues or complex eigenvalues of a non-symmetric real matrix without compute the caluculation?

Comment: That's at least as difficult as computing the number of real zeros of a real polynomial.

Comment: I don't want to perform any calculation.

Comment: You want to just stare at the matrix, and have the number of real eigenvalues pop into your head? I think you're being a bit unrealistic, iacopo.

Comment: I mean, i don't want to calculate the eigenvalues, any sort of condition about the matrix?